# Vim/Perl Regex Tag Match Problem

Tags: regex, perl, vim

I have data that looks like this:

```
[Shift]);[Ctrl][Ctrl+S][Left mouse-click][Backspace][Ctrl]
```

I want to find all **[.*]** tags that have the word **mouse** in them. Keeping in mind non-greedy specifiers, I tried this in **Vim**: `\[.\{-}mouse.\{-}\]`, but this yielded this result,

```
[Shift]);[Ctrl][Ctrl+S][Left mouse-click]
```

Rather than just the desired,

```
[Left mouse-click]
```

Any ideas? Ultimately I need this pattern in Perl syntax as well, so if anyone has a solution in Perl that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\[[^]]*mouse[^[]*\]
```

That is, match a literal opening bracket, then any number of characters that aren't closing brackets, then "mouse," then any number of non-opening-brackets, and finally a literal closing bracket. Should be the same in Perl.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy - your `]` is not properly escaped.

Comment: They're all fine, @Manojlds. Were you not aware that when `[^` is immediately followed by `]`, the `]` is taken literally instead of as the close of the character set? See for yourself: `echo '[Shift]);[Ctrl][Ctrl+S][Left mouse-click][Backspace][Ctrl]' | perl -nE 'm/(\[[^]]*mouse[^[]*\])/; say $1'`. Quoting [perlrecharclass](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html): "if the `]` is the first (or the second if the first character is a caret) character of a bracketed character class, it does not denote the end of the class (as you cannot have an empty class) …"

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is it perl specific? Doesn't match here - http://regexr.com?2tsej

Comment: It's not specific to Perl, @Manojlds. The pattern I gave matches in Vim as well. That's where I tested before posting my answer. [POSIX also allows it.](http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=7&topic=regex)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following regex:

```
\[[^\]]*mouse.*?\]
```